# mysql query: data from last three months

Tags: mysql, join

I am doing a query that is retrieving some data from the past three months, the only problem is that some of the data I am getting doesn't have entries in certain months. Since they have no entries I'd like to mark that month as 0.

My first thought was the create a temp table and left join the labels that I need out of it. But that hasnt been successful.

Can anyone think of a way to do this?

Example: I want the last 3 months of Data and I am getting

```
'Component', 1325.1988
'Component', 554.1652
'Component', 103.6668
'Development', 203.4163
'Development', 59.4500
'Development', 19.7498
'Flash Assets', 285.5334
'Flash Assets', 302.1501
'Flash Assets', 61.1836
'Release', 0.6000
'Release', 2.3666
'Repackage', 416.2169
'Repackage', 5195.0839
'Repackage', 4.5667
'Source Diff', 1.9000
```

Where `'Source Diff' and 'Release'` don't have 3 entries.

Thanks

**Query**

```
SELECT bt.name as 'Labels', 
SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(bs.eventtime, b.submittime))/60) AS 'Data' 
FROM builds b JOIN buildstatuses bs ON bs.buildid = b.id JOIN buildtypes bt 
ON bt.id = b.buildtype WHERE DATE(b.submittime) 
BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH) AND DATE(CURDATE()) 
AND bs.status LIKE 'Started HANDLER' AND b.buildtype != 11 
AND b.buildtype != 5 AND b.buildtype != 4 GROUP BY bt.name, MONTH(b.submittime);
```

**Table Schema**

builds

```
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int(11)          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| submittime    | datetime         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| buildstatus   | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| buildtype     | varchar(20)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| buildid       | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

buildtypes

```
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int(11)          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name          | varchar(200      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

buildstatuses

```
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| buildid    | int(11)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| eventtime  | datetime | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: Can you post your tables schema and query you use?

Comment: Sjoerd has given some links to review. This approach is generally called 'Tally table', details may vary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some similar questions:

- [How to get values for every day in a month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274777/how-to-get-values-for-every-day-in-a-month)
- [Group by day and still show days without rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902297/group-by-day-and-still-show-days-without-rows)
- [MySQL: filling empty fields with zeroes when using GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479773/mysql-filling-empty-fields-with-zeroes-when-using-group-by)